# Backbone: How to replace one model with another in a view?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view that is supposed to display a single model. By clicking links user can select which model is being displayed. When that happens, and the selected model has fetched, how do I tell view to switch to another model? I see three possible options.

1. Somehow rebind the view to a new model and refresh it.
2. Recycle the model object - set the ID of a newly selected model and `fetch()` it, hoping it will magically get refreshed in a view.
3. Delete view, then recreate it with a new model (when it has finished fetching).

The first approach feels like the 'right' one, but I can't find an easy way to do it (setting `model` is easy, but all the events should be rebound for the view to automatically update itself). The second feels weird, might be prone to conflicts (what happens if there are two objects for the models with the same ID?) and might not work at all. The third seems to be too cumbersome. So, what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You might want consider using the ModelBinder library for Backbone: https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder

You have two possible ways of refreshing the view. You either bind the Model to the View once, and then always update the properties in the Model later. This ways when the Model attribute changes, the ModelBinder will automaticly update the View.

The other solution would be to unbind the Model from the View, and rebind it to another Model.

This might give you an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/dazqS/ There is a refreshModel function in the view, that unbinds the old modle, and rebinds the new.

```
refreshModel: function(model){
    this._modelBinder.unbind();
    this.model = model;
    this._modelBinder.bind(this.model, this.el);
}
```